# Network device (Juniper) + FREERADIUS + 2FA

Tags: multi-factor-authentication, freeradius, radius, juniper, google-2fa

Using Juniper EX3400 switch and other vendor network devices. Installed freeradius and able to authenticate users. Want to do 2fa as 2nd level of protection using freeradius. Can anyone share the procedure to achieve this?

Tried below

https://networkjutsu.com/freeradius-with-two-factor-authentication/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.